# How to limit text in a grid to a given number of rows?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

First off, I have created a codesandbox to help with solving this problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/unruffled-swartz-3mkwph?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A3%2C1-67%2C2). I have an app where I am rendering a list of products in a grid format.

```
const products = [
  {
    name: "Beats Studio Pro",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1697075791958-c7cc4863-d790-40f1-baaf-257d73c10e02.jpeg",
    price: 299.99,
  },
  {
    name: "TOZO PA1 Bluetooth Speakers",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1696992546850-4ffe9c74-9f1c-4c1e-9576-ebc8d6a12498.webp",
    price: 35.99,
  },
  {
    name: "Taylor Swift graphic tee",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1696991827463-e8040010-7379-4eef-b425-50c79a559df8.jpeg",
    price: 29.99,
  },
  {
    name: "Tupac t-shirt",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1696969647330-8efe7e9f-6ab0-43e4-9d90-776702902908.jpeg",
    price: 27.99,
  },
  {
    name: "I Paused My Game to Be Here Hat for Men Women",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1697076765217-77fbc11d-b23c-47f4-96c7-a984ec172dd2.jpeg",
    price: 6.99,
  },
  {
    name: "MIATONE QBOX Bluetooth 5.0 Speakers Portable Wireless IPX7 Waterproof",
    image:
      "https://jevonc-next-ecommerce.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1696992686102-1a11dd34-66a9-4ca4-b7aa-cb2fd0015d4f.webp",
    price: 39.99,
  },
];
```

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-10 py-4 px-6">
      {products.map((product, idx) => (
        <div key={idx} className="flex flex-col justify-between">
          <div className="bg-white h-[200px] relative p-5 rounded-md flex items-center justify-center">
            <Image
              src={product.image}
              alt={product.name}
              height={150}
              width={150}
              className="h-[150px] w-[150px] object-contain"
            />
          </div>
          <h2 className="text-ellipsis mt-1">{product.name}</h2>
          <div className="flex justify-between mt-2">
            <span>${product.price}</span>
            <button className="bg-[#5542F6] border-2 border-[#5542F6] text-white px-4 py-1 rounded-md flex items-center gap-1">
              Add to cart
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Some of the names of the products are short while some are long. This creates an issue where the div element that houses the product name is expanding as needed to fit long text. Because of this, the heights of the product name div differ. I used flexbox to get the divs that are all on the same row of the grid to be the same height but product name divs on different rows still have varying heights as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

The product name div on the first row of the grid takes up two lines while the product name div on the second row takes up three lines. I want to fix the size of the product name div (to let's say 2 lines). And I want to cut off any overflow text beyond that. I tried to accomplish this by using `<h2 className="text-ellipsis mt-1">{product.name}</h2>` but it did not work. Help!

*NOTE: My post was tagged as being the duplicate to this post: [Align child elements of different blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks). My question is not about aligning the child elements inside the grid evenly. If you look at the screenshot I have shared, you will see that the elements are already aligned. I need to know how to limit the text to 2 lines and how to use ellipsis to cut off the overflow...

Comment: There was a thread about this yesterday that has some more options than are listed in the thread linked to above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277759/css-grid-of-images-and-headings-misaligns-when-headings-wrap-plus-complication/77278088?noredirect=1#comment136237224_77278088

Comment: My question is different though. Mine is not so much about aligning elements but rather restricting the product name div to a certain height. And making sure the product name div sticks to that height across all rows. Because right now, they are aligned but they are different heights in different rows.

Comment: Ah, okay. Have you tried setting a fixed height? (Not something I would do, but …)

Comment: Yes, that didn't work for me